# Counting True / False values in unique columns per rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas

My DataFrame:

**df**

```
A       B       C       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
5       2       4       True    False   False   True    False   True    False   True    False
2       2       1       True    True    False   False   False   True    False   True    False
5       4       7       False   False   True    False   True    True    False   True    True
4       4       1       False   True    False   False   False   True    False   True    True
2       0       8       False   False   True    False   True    True    False   True    True
```

**My goal:**

To calculate sum per cateogory `1-9` and columns `A`, `B`, `C`.

So that I could answer these kidn of questions:

What is the `sum` of column `A` values where column `1` is `True`, what is the `sum` of `C` where column `5` is `True`.

In reality, I have about 50 categories `1-50` and I want to know if there is a smart way of calculating these sums without having to have this kind of line 50 times:

```
df['Sum of A where 1 is True'] = df.A.where(df.1)).sum()
```

and so on.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filtering by `True`s with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = (df.melt(['A','B','C'], var_name='Type', value_name='mask')
       .loc[lambda x: x.pop('mask')]
       .groupby('Type')
       .sum())
print (df)
       A   B   C
Type            
1      7   4   5
2      6   6   2
3      7   4  15
4      5   2   4
5      7   4  15
6     18  12  21
8     18  12  21
9     11   8  16
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is just `matmul`:

```
# replace your columns accordingly
df[list('123456789')].T @ df[list('ABC')]
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
1   7   4   5
2   6   6   2
3   7   4  15
4   5   2   4
5   7   4  15
6  18  12  21
7   0   0   0
8  18  12  21
9  11   8  16
```